# Given a correlation matrix $B$. What correlation matrix A (maximizes / minimizes) the following: det(A+B)

Tags: matrices, inequalities, determinants

Given correlation matrix $B$ (positive semi-definite with ones in the diagonal).

1)Find the correlation matrix $A$ which maximizes $\det\left(A+B\right)$.
2)Find the correlation matrix $A$ which minimizes $\det\left(A+B\right)$

Comment: if A and B are given there is nothing to maximize/minimize; if A is not given, what will stop you from taking A an arbitrarily large multiple of the unit matrix, so that the determinant of A+B will become arbitrarily large?

Comment: That is because A is a correlation matrix. So it has 1s on the diagonal.

Comment: Actually this is a nice question, though a bit poorly phrased originally, but now it is clearly stated.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that what the OP wanted to say was, given a correlation matrix $B$, find a correlation matrix $A$ that maximizes $\det(A+B)$. Let me cite here a more general theorem that paves the way to a solution.

> **Theorem** Let $A$ and $B$ be Hermitian matrices with eigenvalues $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_n$, respectively. Then,

\begin{equation*}
 \det(A+B) \le \max_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n}\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i + b_{\sigma(i)}).
\end{equation*}

Since correlation matrices are Hermitian positive semidefinite, a specialization of this theorem shows us that
\begin{equation*}
\det(A+B) \le \prod_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i(A) + \lambda_{n-i+1}(B)),
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ is the $i$-largest eigenvalue. Thus, in particular, for a fixed $B$, we just need to pick a suitable $A$ that has the same eigenvectors as $B$ (in permuted order, however), but has the largest possible allowable eigenvalues.

*EDIT* It is not immediate, if these eigenvalues can be easily obtained in closed form. It seems that **in some cases** the optimum solution can be obtained by setting
\begin{equation*}
a_{ij} = \begin{cases}
 -b_{ij} & i \neq j,\\
 1       & i = j
 \end{cases}.
\end{equation*}
In this case, $A+B = 2I_n$. But in general, as noted by the OP in the comments below, this construction does not always work. I am still hoping to be able to get a solution more easily than solving an SDP, but at this point it is not clear whether I can do better than solving an SDP (for the maximization problem).

Comment: And what A would minimize det(A+B)?

Comment: Actually I think there might be something wrong in that proof.  Consider B=[1 .5;.5 1], if A=[1 0;0 1] the det(A+B) is less than if A=[1 -.5;-.5 1].

Comment: Actually that is true---the simple diagonal $A$ is not going to work because correlation matrices can easily have eigenvalues larger than 1. So $A=I_n$ is not the answer, but the answer will be obtained by finding an $A$ for which the 2nd inequality listed above becomes an equality.

Comment: I thought a bit more about it; as the above inequality shows, $A$ will have the same eigenvectors as $B$ (just permuted in opposite order); but it is not immediate what the eigenvalues should be---without that, a closed form solution won't be possible, and this turns into a convex optimization problem, which seems overkill....

Comment: A(i,j)=-B(i,j) works in 2 dimensions. But for larger dimensions this could be impossible because A needs to be hermitian. For example: if B=[1 1 1;1 1 1;1 1 1] then A should be A=[1 -1 -1;-1 1 -1;-1 -1 1] which is not hermitian.

Comment: why is this $A$ not symmetric? $B$ was symmetric to begin with, so $A$ as constructed above will also be symmetric!

Comment: Yes it is symmetric.

Comment: The A as constructed above is not semi-definite positive. So it can not be a correlation matrix. @suvrit

Comment: well, I guess then your only hope is to solve a convex optimization problem to maximize the determinant; there might not be a closed form way to maximize the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: A family of matrices A that fulfills the equality is $A=I-\alpha (B-I)$ with $\alpha \geq 0$.

A has the same eigenvectors than B, but the order of the eigenvalues is inverted because for each eigenvector: $λ(A)=1−α(λ(B)−1)$. <br/> A has 1s in the diagonal and stays semi-definite positive as long as its minimum eigenvalue is: $λ_{min}(A)=1−α(λ_{max}(B)−1)≥0$.<br/> Based on the example I gave above I suspect that is better to use the greatest possible α. @suvrit

Comment: However, before I go on there is something I do not understand about @suvrit reasoning to fulfill the equality. You can have a function f(x) that is always lesser or equal than g(x), $f(x)\leq g(x)$. It might so happen that there is an xo for which the equality is fulfilled $f(xo)=g(xo)$, and yet there might be an x1 such that $f(x1)>f(xo)$. As an example you can take $f(x)=x^4,g(x)=x^2$ in the interval [-.5,.5].